# What is the effect of TSH on the calcitonin?

Tags: endocrinology

I know that TSH is released from the pituitary gland and it motivates the thyroid gland to release thyroxine, and calcitonin is released when the calcium level is high in the blood, but is calcitonin affected by TSH or not, I didn't find a specific answer on google, could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [paper](http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/6432564), where it is postulated that TSH secretion is inhibited by calcitonin. However, the paper is quite old (1984) and I'm not sure if there are any more actual paper.